# If Harry Potter went to Lord Voldemort AFTER Nagini had been killed, would he have survived Voldemort's killing curse?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux, albus-dumbledore

So Harry went to Voldemort in the forest and let Voldemort kill him (thus killing the piece of Voldemort's soul within Harry). If this had taken place AFTER Nagini had been killed, would Harry have been able to come back from that?

Dumbledore says Voldemort tied his life to Harry's when he took Lily's blood into himself. If all of Voldemort's other horcruxes had been destroyed already, would both Harry and Voldemort have been killed at this time?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, he would have because the small piece of Voldemort's soul inside of Harry kept him tethered to life while Voldemort was still alive (and vice versa, IIRC). Check the chapter *Kings Cross* in *Deathly Hallows* -- Dumbledore explains it. ... Is this a duplicate, anyone? My search function is giving me a hard time today. I feel like maybe this has been asked before.

Comment: @Slytherincess: You explained why Harry survived in the Forest in this question – http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/35074/3567 – and the fact that it had nothing to do with Nagini provides the answer to this question, if indirectly.

Comment: Yes but I'm wondering whether Voldemort would have lived, had he attempted to kill Harry after his final Horcrux had been destroyed. If Nagini had been killed, then Harry went to Voldemort in the forest.. Voldemort would have been only a regular man. So Voldemort kills Harry, along with the piece of his soul within Harry.. would either of them survived that?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the killing curse directed at Harry does nothing to the piece of soul residing in Voldemort’s body. Why would that be affected?

Comment: Well Voldemort does go unconscious after his curse hits Harry, just as Harry does. I guess I was assuming his horcrux is what allowed him to come back from that. So as long as Voldemort is alive, then Harry too is alive? Because if Nagini had been killed, then Voldemort would have had no horcruxes to rely on. So I suppose if he attempted to kill Harry after Nagini was dead, he still would have come back from "Kings Cross" anyway, just as Harry did?

Comment: @alexwlchan - Thanks :) And I correct myself: It was Lily's enchantments that kept Harry tethered to life in the forest/Kings Cross, not the piece of Voldemort's soul. Just wanted to clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

***Yes, Harry would have survived, and so would Voldemort***.

The specific sequence of events was as follows:

- Voldemort shoots Avada **at Harry** in the forest.
- Voldemort's Avada severes/destroys the piece of V's soul attached to Harry.
- However, **it did NOT bounce back on him unlike 19 years ago, and does nothing to his own remaint of soul or his body**!

  (remember that what happened the first time he tried to kill Harry, was that his Avada which bounced off of Harry destroyed his body! This didn't happen this time)
- Harry is NOT killed by Avada because he is protected by Lily's protection which still flows through Voldemort's veins due to taking Harry's blood.

  And since Voldemort's body is still alive, that blood still protects Harry.

The important part is that that - since the Avada did NOT bounce back and kill him - the presence or absence of Horcruxes was **irrelevant** to what happened.

What the Horcruxes do in general, and did for him originally, 19 years ago, was **keeping his soul alive** after the Avada Kedavra (which bounced off of Harry) **killed his own body**. Since this didn't happen in the forest, the Horcruxes were not needed.

Horcruxes don't revive people from fainting.

Comment: "Horcruxes don't revive people from fainting." Haha! And thanks, I understand now :)

Comment: @AllieE. - if the answer helps you, the StackExchange standard to thank is to accept the answer (Checkmark to the left of it :)

Comment: @DVK - Don't mislead a new user. She is not obligated to thank you by accepting your answer. She very well may, but it's nice to see multiple answers from which to choose. It looks like this is duplicate anyway.